802.1X EAP-TLS issue on LAN (FortiAuth, Windows 10/11, Cisco)
I'm dealing with a problem and could use some guidance.
We have a FortiAuthenticator as RADIUS server with a public certificate.
We also have two internal CAs (RSA/ECC) based on Microsoft, although there are some extensions. However, I am focusing on the ECC one for now (let’s leave the internal RSA aside).
The 802.1x process itself is functional and running on Cisco switches (e.g., C9300).
The problem is that when connecting to the network, the client does not trust the server certificate.
The certificate is fa.domain.eu
If I disable server identity verification by certificate, it works fine. When I enable "don’t prompt user to authorize new servers," no prompt appears, but the client fails to authenticate.
I tried adding both the Root CA (Sectigo/Usertrust) and Geant (even though it's the Issuer) to the root store in the computer certificates. Geant also appears among the Issuers.
But it still doesn’t work. Any tips? Or what else should I add to check?
Pictures here.
https://imgur.com/a/6p1DZXg
Thank you in advance.
FA.domain.eu cert
Windows couldnt verify server identity
Radius EAP-Config
Cert config in GPO's
Usertrust chain seems ok
Usertrust root in trusted CA's
